# solving Moore-Penrose inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve some Moore-Penrose inverse problems.

First I already solve that $(I_n  + P)^+ = I_n - \frac{1}{2}* P$  when P is hat matrix.

ex) X : n*p matrix, rank(X) = p and $P = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$

But I failed to calculate $(I_n - P)^+$.

I used eigenvalue decomposition $P=VDV^T$, then D has diagonal values 0,1 that each has n-p and p repeats and $VV^T=V^TV=I_n$

\begin{align}
(I_n -P)^+ &= (I_n - VDV^T)^+ \\
           &= (VV^T - VDV^T)^+ \\
           &= V(I_n - D)^+V^T 
\end{align}

Can I expand this equation more? like $(I_n  + P)^+ = I_n - \frac{1}{2}* P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(I- P)$  is real symmetric and idempotent $(I- P)^2=(I- P)$-- i.e. it is an orthogonal projection.  So setting

$(I- P)^{+} := (I- P)$
it is immediate that all 4 properties of the Moore-Penrose inverse are met, and by uniqueness property, this *is* the Moore-Penrose inverse.